# Dynamic change the database config variable in lumen

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

I have early updated the config variable on the run in laravel. My requirement is to update the same in lumen . i am trying to change the database connection dynamically.  I have earlier done the same in laravel and it's working fine .

```
            $config = config()->all();
            $config['database']['connections']['mysql']['database'] = "dynamic_db_name"; 
            $config['database']['connections']['mysql']['username'] = "dynamic_db_username";
            $config['database']['connections']['mysql']['password'] = "dynamic_db_password";
            config($config);
            Artisan::call('config:clear'); //cause 500 error in lumen , i have use the Artisan Facdes also
            \DB::purge('mysql');

            $category =  \App\Models\Category::get();
            dd($category); // fetch me data from database A instead of B
```

If i dd the value of config , i get the same old value of config variables, instead of updated one.  please tell what am i missing

Comment: where do you dd ? i reproduced your case and it is working.

Comment: its work fine is laravel . the issue is with lumen

Comment: Yeah i tested in lumen. when you  `return config('database.connections.mysql')` at the end of all - it should return all the config (i tested in lumen and returns what is set)

Comment: @Ersoy , i have update the question with dd

Comment: What happens if you replace `purge` line with `DB::reconnect('mysql');` ?

Comment: it will return  all the config, but if you run  $config = config()->all(); than you will find the same old value (new value didn't get update)

Comment: @Ersoy, i have use DB::reconnect('mysql'); also, but i guess i am unable to clear the cache using cache:clear

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like this. This is working for me lumen 7.x.
In your database.php

```
'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', 5432),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
        'prefix' => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
        'schema' => env('DB_SCHEMA', 'public'),
        'sslmode' => env('DB_SSL_MODE', 'prefer'),
    ],
```

Then your controller file

```
$db_name = 'xxxx';
$username = 'yyyyy';
$password = 'zzzz';  
config(["database.connections.pgsql" => [
     'driver' => 'pgsql',
     'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
     'port' => env('DB_PORT', 5432),
     'database' => $db_name,
     'username' => $username
     'password' => $password,
     'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
     'prefix' => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
     'schema' => env('DB_SCHEMA', 'public'),
     'sslmode' => env('DB_SSL_MODE', 'prefer'),
     ]]);
```